# Using jsonp with the django-rest-framework

Tags: jsonp, django-rest-framework

The django rest framework release notes claim that JSONP support was added back in 0.3.0. I also found a JSONPRenderer class in the framework.  However, I can't seem to find any documentation on how to use the thing... I'm fairly new to jsonp.

Has anyone ever successfully used jsonp with the django rest framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While posting this, I found the answer (or at least AN answer). It appears that the jsonp renderer is available by default on a ModelResource, so all you need to do is add "?format=json-p" to the requesting url.

Comment: [Here's](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers.html#jsonprenderer) the official documentation.

Comment: Just to save a few minutes to everyone googling it:

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONPRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),

Comment: update: it used to be part of the django rest framework distribution, but it's now available as a third-party package  http://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jsonp/

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone is looking for `jsonp`.

First ([docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/)):

`pip install djangorestframework-jsonp`

And then modify your REST framework settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
  'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework_jsonp.renderers.JSONPRenderer',
  ),
}
```

Finally make sure that your url contains `?format=jsonp` and not `?format=json-p`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework_jsonp.renderers import JSONPRenderer, JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.response import Response

class YourClass(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (JSONPRenderer, JSONRenderer)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        your_result = {{ your serialized result }}
        return Response({'status': 'success', 'result': your_result})
```